# Small widths in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I've run into a problem with Google Chrome (version: 15.0.874.121 m): when a block's width is less than 0.99px (precisely), it's displayed incorrectly — with the width of the inner text.

Sample code:

```
<style>
.frame { float: left; border: solid; }
.frame div { width: 0.98px; overflow: hidden; }
</style>
<div class="frame"><div>Long text</div></div>
```

And here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bDTgX/1/

The same code works well in Firefox, Opera, and Internet Explorer.

What could be the reason (a bug in Chrome?) — and how could it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say this is a bug really, but it is just how webkit is rounding sub-pixel metrics.  Note that it's considering .99 to round up, anything else it's rounding down...

http://jsfiddle.net/bDTgX/9/

If it rounds down to zero, it's just ignored all together as it assumes you've made a mistake.  So, therefore, anything less than .99px would be ignored and default to with: auto;  If you don't like the way this is taking, use max-width: and it will conform to it's zero px.  But the rounding is set, you will just have to deal with that.  Sub-pixel rendering just isn't supported on webkit like it is on gecko (firefox).

Comment: This sounds reasonable, and it's rather strange that WebKit has the problem, because I found it while trying to use jQuery.animate({ width: 'toggle' }) - it causes flickering & glitches in Chrome, while working OK in other browsers (using 1px instead of 'toggle' would do the trick, by the way).
That's weird behavior. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with webkit and fractional pixels.

http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Comment: Thanks. However, it's not exactly the same, because in this case 0.98px should be rounded to 1px or 0px - but it's rounded to the width of the inner content. And other fractional widths seem to work well in Chrome/Webkit.